# Сортировка колонок в ListView по нажатию

Tags: delphi, listview, сортировка

Как реализовать сортировку колонок в `ListView` по нажатию на название колонки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTFM [TListView.CustomSort](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TCustomListView_CustomSort.html).

Параметры метода - адрес функции сравнения (возвращающая -1,0,1 для двух элементов), и произвольное число, куда можно передать индекс колонки, которую нажали.

```
function CustomSortProc(Item1, Item2: TListItem; ParamSort: integer): integer; stdcall;
begin
  if ParamSort=0 then
    Result := CompareText(Item1.Caption,Item2.Caption)
  else
    if Item1.SubItems.Count>ParamSort-1 then
    begin
      if Item2.SubItems.Count>ParamSort-1 then
        Result := CompareText(Item1.SubItems[ParamSort-1],Item2.SubItems[ParamSort-1])
      else
        Result := 1;
    end
    else
      Result:=-1;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1ColumnClick(Sender: TObject;
  Column: TListColumn);
begin
  ListView1.CustomSort(@CustomSortProc, Column.Index);
end;
```